# Fast way to apply function elementwise to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a sets of numpy arrays which I create using

```
for longtuple in itertools.product([0,1], repeat = n + m -1 ):
    outputs = set(np.convolve(v, longtuple, 'valid').tostring() for v in itertools.product([0,1], repeat = m))
    if (len(outputs) == 2**m):
        print "Hooray!"
```

However I would actually like to take every element x of `np.convolve(v, longtuple, 'valid')` and apply `x >> k & 1` (for values of k that I will specify) and then add that resulting array to the set instead. Is there an efficient way to do this?

---

My use of set and tostring() is simply to see if there are any duplicates. I am not sure it is correct however.

Comment: just be aware that for example `-0.` and `0.` are different in this sense...

Comment: @seberg Oh!  Which test makes them the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just take the result of convolve and apply your expression to it:

```
set((np.convolve(v, longtuple, 'valid') >> k & 1).tostring() for v in itertools.product([0,1], repeat = m))
```

Comment: I am worried my use of tostring() is wrong. I am only using it so I can add the arrays to the set.  But it doesn't make sense to do  >> k & 1 after calling tostring() does it?

Comment: Sorry, I messed it up.  See my edited answer.  You want to do `>> k & 1` on the result of convolve, then apply `tostring` after that.